# Caching maven dependencies while running gitlab-ci with docker

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am using Gitlab-cli to run my builds and publish to docker registry on every commit to the master branch. Below is the build file named `gitlab-ci.yml`. How can I cache the image layers inside my registry so that if there is no change in the `pom.xml`, the image will use the cache version of the docker image.

```
docker-build-master:
  # Official docker image.
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  before_script:
    - docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build --pull -t "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE" .
    - docker push "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE"
  only:
    - master
```